# Not able to connect to SharePoint Online Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I have tried the same code in with another domain site on my laptop, works fine. But, when I run the same script on a Windows Server 12 R2 on another domain site it throws an exception as shown in the image.

[image: Exception]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a problem with the format.You could try to save as ps1 file and execute it again.
Or you could try this:

```
$siteURL="https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/dev"
$userId = "amos@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"  
$pwd = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString 
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL)
$creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userId, $pwd)  
$ctx.credentials = $creds
```

It works well on my Windows Server 12 R2

Comment: The file is already saved as **GetListItems.ps1**, My code is also the same and has tested in Powershell ISE and SPO Management Shell

Comment: The issue was with the Server on with the code was running, ***port no. 80*** was blocked